# Looking for OpenNi2 sample code or place to download OpenNi1.5

Tags: kinect, openni

I am trying to get started with developing Kinect Application using OpenNi.I dont seem to find any sample code for OpenNi2.I could find code for OpenNI 1.5 though. Where would i be able to find it?
And I am also looking for the older version OpenNI1.5 since all the documentations are based on it.Where would i find a link to download it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After you download OpenNI 2 and unzip it there is a **Samples** folder.
You will want to start with something like **SimpleViewer**.

I recommend checking out the [OpenNI Migration Guide](http://www.openni.org/openni-migration-guide/#.UcW8wfaG2KY) as well.

Also, you can find previous version of OpenNI (including 1.5.4.0) [here](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/#.UcW92PZhl14)

Comment: I am now trying to run a sample code from the OpenNI 1.5 documentation..It's giving me an error on a particular variable..I dont know why..the code is in my new answer..Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello George, I have updated the question..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252653/openni-1-5could-not-run-code-from-documentation