# OpenNI 1.5::Could not run code from documentation

Tags: kinect, openni

I am trying to run a sample code from the OpenNI 1.5 documentation.I have imported the library required XnCppWrapper.h so that I can use C++.The code has only one error on a particular variable "bshouldrun".I know that it should be declared as something but since I am new at this and the documentation does not contain anything above the main, I dont know what to declare it as..Please help!!
And thanks in advance.

```
 #include <XnOpenNI.h>
 #include <XnCppWrapper.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {

    XnStatus nRetVal = XN_STATUS_OK;

    xn::Context context;

   // Initialize context object
   nRetVal = context.Init();
   // TODO: check error code

   // Create a DepthGenerator node
   xn::DepthGenerator depth;
   nRetVal = depth.Create(context);
   // TODO: check error code

   // Make it start generating data
   nRetVal = context.StartGeneratingAll();
   // TODO: check error code

   // Main loop
   while (bShouldRun) //<-----------------------------**ERROR;bShouldRun Undefined**
   {
       // Wait for new data to be available
       nRetVal = context.WaitOneUpdateAll(depth);
       if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
      {
          printf("Failed updating data: %s\n", xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
          continue;
      }

       // Take current depth map
       const XnDepthPixel* pDepthMap = depth.GetDepthMap();

       // TODO: process depth map
   }

   // Clean-up
   context.Shutdown();

   }
```

Comment: What is the name of the OpenNI 1.5 sample you are trying to compile ?

Comment: I dont think it's in samples folder. I used this from the OpenNI users guide.It's called "Basic Functions:Initialize,Create a Node and Read Data"pg20

Comment: How about trying to compile one of the simpler samples that come with OpenNI and once you've that done, start modifying it ?

Comment: I just tried the SimpleViewer sample.And now it says "cannot find file afxres.h".Am i missing something in terms of installation?

Comment: I am running Windows 7

Comment: And what are you using to compile ? (VisualStudio/Qt/CodeBlocks/Makefiles/etc.)

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 to compile

Comment: I just tried to compile samples from OpenNI2 and not OpenNI 1.5..only the sample viewer works.For the rest it says it could not find the corresponding .lib file..For example, for simplehandtracker,it says 'Could not find SimpleHandTracker.lib" file.Would you know why?

Comment: See the answer bellow

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to run a sample from Visual Studio 2010 Express on Windows (8):

1. Opened the NiSimpleViewer.vcxproj VS2010 project from C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNI\Samples\NiSimpleViewer
2. Edited OpenNI.rc to comment out `#include "afxres.h"` on line 10(might be missing this because I'm using Express version, not sure. Your machine might compile this fine/not complain about the missing header file)
3. Enabled **Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols > Microsoft Symbol Servers** (to get past missing pdb files issue)
4. Optionally edit the `SAMPLE_XML_PATH` to `"SamplesConfig.xml"` rather than the default `"../../../Data/SamplesConfig.xml"`, otherwise you need to run the sample executable from ..\Bin\Debug\NiSimpleViewer.exe by navigating to there rather than using the Ctrl+F5. A;so copy the SamplesConfig.xml file into your sample folder as you can see bellow

Here are a few images to illustrate some of the above steps:
[image: remove afxres.h]

[image: Microsoft Symbol Servers enable]

[image: SAMPLE XML PATH mod]

[image: Sample xml copied to the folder]

You can also compile the NiHandTracker sample, which sounds closer to what you need.
So this explains the setup for OpenNI 1.5 which is what your question is about.

I've noticed your OpenNI 2 lib issue in the comments. It should be a matter of linking against SimpleHandTracker.lib which you can do via **Project Properties (right-click project->select Properties) > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > Edit.**
[image: lib linking]
I don't have OpenNI2 setup on this machine, but assuming SimpleHandTracker.lib would be in OpenNI_INSTALL_FOLDER\Lib. Try a file search in case I might be wrong.